# how do i delete a line with pattern matcher after i found ## using regex

Tags: java, regex

its for removing a vi am file comment

```
 content = content.replaceAll("##", "");//if found ## in line then remove
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: i dont know how to write a regex that remove each line it sees double ## in and didnt found anything, i mean whole line not only the ##

Comment: Could you supply the text your searching?

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 :

```
Pattern notToMatch = Pattern.compile("##");
Files.lines(Paths.get(fileLocationString))
    .filter(l -> ! notToMatch.matcher(l).find())
    .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
```

It will return a String that contains the input file, lines with "##" excluded. The String can then be written to the files to overwrite them.

- `Files.lines(path)` returns a `Stream` of the lines of a file.
- `Stream.filter` enables us to filter out lines that does not match a `Predicate`. Here we use a lambda as a Predicate to return True IFF the line does not match the "##" Pattern
- `.collect` will wrap the incoming `Stream` into an object that is returned. Here we use `Collectors.joining(separator)` to join them back into a single `String`.

I would personally suggest doing this transformation outside of Java if it hasn't got to be included in an existing Java process. In a bash + GNU tools environnement, the file transformation would be as easy as `grep -v "##" filePath > filePath`.

Comment: the lambad gives me an error saying pattern cannot be applied to lambada paremeter and cant import the collectors or i missing something

Comment: oh i guess since its java 7 i cant use collectors

Answer (score 1):

found solution by playing with regex, hope it helps someone

```
content = content.replaceAll("##.*", "");//remove comments
```